# Heroku images resolution

Tags: python, heroku

I deployed a Twitter bot to Heroku a day ago. This bot tweets a text with an image every hour. The problem is that the image resolution is lower than the file actually is.

When I run the program from the console the image resolution is fine. It just happens when it is runned on Heroku.

I use urllib for downloading the pictures and tweepy to publish them.

Here's the code I use to download the images:

```
picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"irc_cc\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img").get_attribute("src")
sleep(1)
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(picture, "file.jpg")

except:
    print("Cant get image")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you expand on "The problem is that the image resolution is lower than the file actually is"? Where are you seeing a low-resolution image? Can you be more specific about what "low resolution" means? Where are you seeing a full resolution image?